# Change of variables - Square

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $R$ be the region in the plane bounded by the square with vertices $(1,0), (0,1), (1,2), (2,1)$. Evaluate the integral:

$ \int \int_R (x+y)^2 \space \sin(x-y) dA $

I tried making $u = |x-1|$ and $v = -|x-1| + 2$, but that made the jacobian zero and now I'm stuck.

Comment: I would like to make $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$.  This rotates the square to be parallel to the axes. Does that help?

Comment: How do I then find the bounds on $u$ or $v$?

Comment: Calculate $u$ and $v$ at each corner of the square.  You will have two values for $u$ and two values for $v$.  The lower of each is the lower limit, the upper is the upper limit.  That is the nice thing about having the square parallel to the axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $u = x + y$, and $v = x - y$, and let $A = (0,1)$, $B = (1,2)$, $C = (2,1)$, and $D = (1,0)$, then the equation of lines:

$AB$: $x - y = -1$

$CD$: $x - y = 1$

$AD$: $x + y = 1$

$BC$: $x + y = 3$.

So: $\dfrac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = -\dfrac{1}{2}$. So:

$I = \int_{-1}^1\int_{1}^3 u^2sinv \cdot (-1/2dudv) = 0$